# Selenium webdriver - why same code behave differently in different browser drivers

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am developing an automation testing framework using Selenium webdriver and Java. I have almost done and when I run my tests using Firefox driver, it always works fine. But when I run the same code in Chrome driver

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element
>   state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be
>   manipulated

exception occurs at almost every 'findElement()' statement. When the same code is run in Internet Explorer

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
>   occurs.

I wonder why the same code behaves differently in different browser drivers. Please mention what are the things keep in mind while developing automation framework that run flawlessly in different browser drivers

Comment: All browsers are different. However, the vast majority of 'differences' are user error caused by trying to interact with web elements before they are ready for use. Does your framework include these checks?

Comment: Yes. I use different Selenium waits to check presence/availability of elements before any actions are being performed

Comment: Have you got some example code that works differently across the two browsers?

Comment: I click on login menu using the code 'JavascriptLibrary jsLib=new JavascriptLibrary();
  jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver, "triggerMouseEventAt", element, "click","0,0");'. To assert if error message is present I use the code 'new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, "Please enter username")'

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide some code snippet

Answer (score 0):

"triggerMouseEventAt" ????

Different browsers render screens slightly differently. Mouse events are probably the least likely things to expect to work across browsers.

driver.findElement(By ....).click() 
is much more likely to work across browsers.

Comment: I can't click on menu using 'driver.findElement(By ....).click()' command, it always throws 'NoSuchElementFound' exception, even if different conditional waits are used. After a long research I found "triggerMouseEventAt" only working perfectly on the login menu

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

We can find element in different browser using:

1. Javascript: Javascript engine is different in different browser
2. ClassName
3. Id
4. XPath: XPath also works differently in different browser
5. CSS Selector: This method should also work differently

Best method should be to test for suitable method and use which works.

Once I had read a good book on "How browsers Work". You can also try that: http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm